# jQuery reusable elements and child access

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a website where I need to create reusable elements. Here is an example:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
</div>
```

So - in a for loop I want to clone this element many times and change title and description content.

For this reason, I've placed my template in a hidden element like this in my page:

```
<div id="templates" style="display:none">    
    <div class="item">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="description"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure this is a good methodology to create reusable elements in a page. This is what I could think of.

So I get my templates element by this on page load:

```
var templates = $("templates");
```

After this point for every element I want to reuse (when I need to reuse), I do this:

```
var item = templates.find(".item");
```

So how will I proceed by creating my new elements and changinf their titles and descriptions? I've tried the following for the `#container` div being the main container object for all generated elements:

```
$("#container").html(item.clone().html())
```

But that just gives me a single object. I simply can't get my head around how I should proceed with this.

Any comments are appreciated - also please enlighten me if this is a bad methodology, I would love to know a good one.

Thanks.

Comment: whats wrong in holding that html string in a variable instead of keeping it in DOM

Comment: If you do cloning each time that will affect the performance. But using that elements as a string will be more efficient compared to that.

Comment: for readibility, nothing more. I don't like to keep html strings in js as it's hard to edit and read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can use your templating method, grab a clone, and change its elements by the classes, and then add that clone to the body element

```
$("#clone").click(function () {
    var clone = $("#templates .item").clone()
    $(".title", clone).html("Title")
    $(".description", clone).html("Desc")
    $("body").append(clone)
})
```

I wouldnt worry about performance until you need to run this tens of thousands of times

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could reach elements like $(selector, parent)

Answer (score 0):

I feel writing hidden content to a document, that will never be shown is incorrect.

Instead you can using some templating framework or template plugin like this one
https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template

You need to create html files for these template and provide object to fill template

```
$("#template-container").loadTemplate("Templates/template.html",
    {
        author: 'Joe Bloggs',
        date: '25th May 2013',
        authorPicture: 'Authors/JoeBloggs.jpg',
        post: 'This is the contents of my post'
    });
```

template.html

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <div data-content="author"></div>
    <div data-content="date"></div>
    <img data-src="authorPicture" data-alt="author"/>
    <div data-content="post"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: I feel like this is just complicating things even more, a lot of things to change and keep for a single document. I like to keep things as simple as possible that's why I go like this